# Access deepen elements in big hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

```
<table id="financial101_tab1" class="dxrpControl_Moderno dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="financial101_tab1_RPC" class="dxrp dxrpcontent">
            <input id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1ATI" type="hidden" value="1" name="Block..."></input>
            <div id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1" class="dxtcLite_Moderno dxtc-top">
                <ul id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1_TC" class="dxtc-strip dxtc-stripContainer">
                    <li id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1_T0" class="dxtc-tab dxtc-lead">
                        <a class="dxtc-link">
                            <b class="dxtc-text dx-vam">
                                Гисторгамма
```

I need no change that text of class

```
<b class="dxtc-text dx-vam">
```

and background of

```
<li id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1_T0" class="dxtc-tab dxtc-lead">
```

Almost tried

```
$(".dxrpControl_Moderno.dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno").each(function ()
            {
                if ($(this).find(".dxtc-tab.dxtc-lead").find(".dxtc-link").find("dxtc-text.dx-vam").text() == "Гистограмма")
                {
                    alert("Гистограмма");
                }
            });
```

but no message appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.trim()` to trim spaces in your text:

```
if ($(this).find(".dxtc-tab.dxtc-lead").find(".dxtc-link").find("dxtc-text.dx-vam").text().trim()  == "Гистограмма"
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fVLbZ/2/)**

Comment: but also interested in applying background style for `<li id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1_T0" class="dxtc-tab dxtc-lead">` if it's possible

Comment: You can use: `$('#BlockControlfinancial101_tab1_T0').css('background','Your style here');`

Comment: but it's problematic for me access via id, id's are unique, i need to use common classes, can you advice some ideas?